# How to fix an arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, list

So arrayLists are a first for me, and as far as I know I've been doing everything correctly and following the examples provided to me by my online course. HOWEVER, for some reason or other I have a line underlined red...which I will get to in a moment after a brief explanation of this program.

This program allows you to input an employee information and after pressing the 'list' button (listButton) it outsput in the employeeField etc etc. That basically sums up this program.

```
public class EmployeeView extends FrameView {

    class Company { //this is the class to allow me to put 'company'  in the arrayList...
        String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate, mileage;

        Company (String _ID, String _firstName,String _lastName, String _annualSal, String _startDate) {
            ID = _ID;
            firstName = _firstName;
            lastName = _lastName;
            annualSal = _annualSal;
            startDate = _startDate;
        }
    }

    /** Define the ArrayList */
    ArrayList <Company> inventory = new ArrayList <Company>();


    private void AddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String c;
        String ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate; 

        ID = IDField.getText(); //all this stuff grabs info from the Fields...which will then be stored in the array
        firstName = firstNameField.getText();
        lastName = lastNameField.getText();
        annualSal = annualSalField.getText();
        startDate = startDateField.getText();
```

The two lines below this is the culprit. I suppose "new"  is't nessisary but it was there in the example so that's why I am using it...however when I get rid rid of it only 'company' is underlined and the 'c' in the 2nd line is underlined instead of having the entire line underlined. Anyways I hope this is making sense...since its (from what I know of) my only problem.

```
        c = new Company(ID, firstName, lastName, annualSal, startDate);
        inventory.add(c);
    }

    private void ListActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        String temp="";

        for (int x=0; x<=inventory.size()-1; x++) {
            temp = temp + inventory.get(x).ID + " "
                    + inventory.get(x).firstName + " "
                    + inventory.get(x).lastName + " "
                    + inventory.get(x).annualSal + " "
                    + inventory.get(x).startDate + "\n";
        }
        employeeTArea.setText(temp);


}
```

Comment: What compilation error are you receiving?

Comment: Did you hover over the underline to find out what the error is? Have you tried compiling your program?

Comment: Good thinking there...It said it was already defined, so I just deleted the first declaration and bingo! Problem solved. I can't help but feel a little like an idiot now lol, all well!

Answer (score 5):

You've declared `c` to be a `String`; you can't assign a `Company` directly to a `String`.

Change your declaration of `c` to be `Company`.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is declared as a `String` above.  It should be type `Company` instead.